# Azure AD authentication failed using idToken or accessToken. Which one should I use?

Tags: javascript, jwt, azure-active-directory, passport.js, azure-ad-msal

In the azure active directory documentation it states:

idToken: `id_tokens are sent to the client application as part of an OpenID Connect flow. They can be sent along side or instead of an access token, and are used by the client to authenticate the user.`

accessToken: `Access tokens enable clients to securely call APIs protected by Azure`

I am using [msal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/msal) to log the user into my vue application (single page web app) and try to acquire accessToken to my REST API.

My goal is to separate the auth flow of the frontend from the backend that way in the future several client applications can access the REST API through accessTokens.

When logging in, I get prompted a permission popup and afterwards receive both an idToken `token.idToken.rawIdToken` and an accessToken `token.accessToken` in the token response of `msal.aquireTokenSilent(config)`.

I am using passport and [passport-azure-ad](https://github.com/AzureAD/passport-azure-ad) with the `BearerStrategy` to validate the accessToken as a middleware. If I pass the `token.accessToken` with the Authorization Bearer header, I receive a `authentication failed due to: invalid signature` error. If I pass the 
`token.idToken.rawIdToken` instead, I receive `authentication failed due to: jwt issuer is invalid` if I set `validateIssuer: true` in the bearer strategy config.

First, I want to find out which token would be the one to use? Both are valid jwt token (https://jwt.ms/) but they contain different fields. I guess as of right now the idToken sounds more promising but I am not sure if it is the way to go as I would need to specify the clientId of the frontend as the audience field in the backend, otherwise it throws `authentication failed due to: jwt audience is invalid`. So this is not the way to go for multiple clients, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use access tokens issued by AAD to secure your own custom web APIs. Note, that you must first create a custom scope, and then have the user consent to that scope. Once you have done that, your application will be issued a token for that scope (access tokens are issued per resource, meaning you can't protect your custom Web API with a token intended for MS Graph, for example).

See my comment [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/1040#issuecomment-540810355) for more info.

Comment: Thanks! This was the answer I was looking for. If you have your own API and your own scope, you have to aquire a new accessToken! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We use ID Tokens to check that user is either authenticated or not and get their account details. Access token is used to just secure api calls.

You can read more on Azure documentation, specifically:

> ID Tokens should be used to validate that a user is who they claim to be and get additional useful information about them - it shouldn't be used for authorization in place of an access token.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/id-tokens

Comment: Thank you for your response. As I wrote, my goal is to secure my API calls which means I would need the accessToken but it has the wrong signature. That's why I am confused.

Comment: We had to specify tons of things in the azure portal in b2c section, correct scopes, policies, registered client ids & urls .. it's ... fun! ;p

Comment: @Andre - Access Tokens are used to secure Azure resources. If your goal is to protect your own resources (API endpoints) use Identity Tokens. Access Tokens are opaque. Don't bother trying to decode them. Call an Azure endpoint to validate them.